# Can someone explain me the sentence about ideals?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, ideals

Can someone explain me the sentence:

"If $R=K[x]$ the prime ideals are $\langle f(x)\rangle $ where $f(x)$ is an irreducible polynomial in $K[x]$ and $\langle 0\rangle $, and again $\langle f(x)\rangle  $ $\ f(x)$ is also maximal."

?

Comment: Could it read "... and again $(f(x))$ is also maximal."?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I formatted it with LATEX.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I found it in that way in my lecture slides. Isn't it correct formulated?

Comment: @user159870, isn't there some comma or period or something in "and again $\;\langle f(x)\rangle\;f(x)\;$ is also..."

Comment: @Timbuc I found that in that way. How should it be?

Comment: @user159870, most probably as Hagen suggested: "...and again, $\;\langle f(x)\rangle\;$ is also maximal" (meaning, $\;f(x)\;$ is irreducible iff $\;I:=\langle f(x)\rangle\;$ is prime iff $\;I\;$ is maximal. This is true **only** if $\;K\;$ is a field, and in general it is not true that prime $\;\implies\;$ maximal).

Comment: @Timbuc So to apply this in an exercise which demands to show that the ideal $I=<f(x)>$ is maximal, where $f(x)$ is irreducible, we have to show first that $K$ is a field and then that $I$ is prime?

Comment: @Timbuc Ok!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notation $\langle a_1,\dots,a_n \rangle$  for $a_i$ in a ring $R$ sometimes means the ideal generated by $a_i$. So $\langle f(x) \rangle$ is the same as $(f(x))$ in other notation, or simply the set $\{f(x)g(x): g(x) \in K[x]\}$. The statement is saying a prime ideal of $K[x]$ is either the zero ideal, or a maximal one which is of the form $\langle f(x) \rangle$ for $f(x)$ irreducible.

Comment: So to apply this in an exercise which demands to show that the ideal $I=<f(x)>$ is maximal, where $f(x)$ is irreducible, we have to show first that $K$ is a field and then that $I$ is prime?

Comment: My answer assumed that $K$ is a field to begin with, otherwise the statement in your question is not true. To show $\langle f(x) \rangle$ is maximal, one way would be to show $K[x]/\langle f(x)\rangle$ is a field (not the same as $K$ typically). But it's probably easier to just show $f(x)$ is irreducible.

Comment: So we show that $f(x)$ is irreducible in $K[x]$ and we are done. Correct?

Comment: Assuming $K$ is in fact a field, yes, if you show $f(x)$ is irreducible, then $\langle f(x) \rangle$ is maximal.